# Is there any significance of booze/getting drunk?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I found some pirate rum and used it like a potion. The screen got blurry for a bit but then everything was normal. Is there any point to alcohol in this game other than just to make your screen blurry for a couple seconds?

Comment: The rotmg wiki is a great resource for finding answers to questions like this if you run into an unknown item again in the future: http://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god

Comment: @Dreamypants: yeah google lead me there, but that page didnt really answer my question. That definitely is my go to source now for all my mad god stuff now though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Pirate Rum](http://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god/pirate-rum) is completely useless, it just blurs your screen for a while.

[image: Pirate Rum effects]

However, the other alcoholic drinks ([Wines](http://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god/wines)) in the game do have a use; they're potent HP/MP potions. They're dropped by enemies in Oryx's Wine Cellar though, so they're rare and hard to get.

Comment: Do the others all have the same blur effect?

Comment: `other alcoholic drinks in the game do have a use; they're potent HP/MP potions` just like real life :)

Comment: @BenBrocka I don't think so, but I can't be sure. I've never been in the Wine Cellar, its incantation is ridiculously rare.

Comment: Thanks! This game is addictive!!! i need to keep my fingers on the potion buttons a little better though.. and not have them equipped with Pirate Rum...